# What is the correct way to clear an array in Haxe?

Tags: haxe

What would be the most performant way to clear an array in Haxe?
Currently I am just assigning an empty array to the variable.

I found this on the Internet:

```
public static function clear(arr:Array<Dynamic>) {
    #if cpp
    arr.splice(0, arr.length);
    #else
    untyped arr.length = 0;
    #end
}
```

Is this the best way? I am concerned with two targets, JS and CPP.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the most part you can simply use reassignment to an empty array to clear the array; this only becomes problematic if the reference to the array is important.  In that case, what you have works well.

That's about it for the answer, but for curiosity's sake, I decided to try timing some of the ways to clear arrays.  Unfortunately, I haven't used Haxe in a while and something in my computer's configurations must have changed, so I can only compile to Neko and HTML5 at the moment.  Regardless, results were interesting.

For the test, I ran four different clear algorithms through arrays ranging from 8 to 1048576 integers in length.  The algorithms were as follows:

Splice Clear:

```
array.splice(0, array.length);
```

Length Clear:

```
untyped array.length = 0;
```

Assignment Clear:

```
array = [];
```

Pop Clear:

```
while (array.length > 0)
    array.pop();
```

All times shown below represent the total time taken to perform the same operation one million times.

In Neko:

- **Splice**: 0.51 seconds
- **Length**: 0.069 seconds
- **Assignment**: 0.34 seconds
- **Pop**: 0.071 to 0.179 seconds (scales linearly as the array gets bigger)

In HTML5:

- **Splice**: 0.29 seconds
- **Length**: 0.046 seconds
- **Assignment**: 0.032 seconds
- **Pop**: 0.012 seconds

These tests were run on a 64-bit Windows 7 machine and Firefox.

I'm a bit surprised the while loop method was the fasted algorithm in javascript; it makes me think something is going on there.  Otherwise, the length method is good on platforms that support it.

My tests are on [Github](https://github.com/Auroratide/Sandbox/tree/master/src/com/auroratide/sandbox/cleararray) in case anyone wants to peer review the methods and perhaps try out the tests on platforms other than Neko and HTML5.

Comment: `array = [];` creates a new instance, which might lead to unexpected results if you have references to the old array.